# Android L Ripple Effect-How to disable ripple effect of a thumb on my seekbar?

Tags: android, seekbar, ripple

I am design my custom seekbar . And I want to make the thumb transparent , but it still has ripple effect . Anybody has some advise ?

Answer (score 40):

set android:background="@null"
This should turn off the ripple effect for the seekbar.